# Android Location based services Alert system

Tags: java, android, gps

HI I Am student planning to develop an Android App which is similar to location Alert based.
My idea is to add the information (ie. longitude and latitude) of particular location  in a database such as SQLlite and use that to alert the users when they reach that location.

Comment: What do you want in it then???
Is this a valid question?

Comment: I need  key Idea how to implement it Atish. I am looking for a sample project which is kind of similar to mine.